# ´libroscpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory´ Error

Tags: ros, libroscpp, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Turtlebot3 WIth ROS Kinetic and Linux 16.04

Everything was working fine until i had trouble installing a python bluetooth library. when the library finally worked it broke ROS. (Atleast i think that broke it)
When i try to run the command `roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_empty_world.launch` or `roscore` i now get the error

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/rosout/rosout: error while loading shared libraries: libroscpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [5196]
[rosout-1] process has died [pid 5196, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/rosout/rosout __name:=rosout __log:=/home/pieter/.ros/log/7ffad4de-6459-11ea-bb82-4074e0a32f05/rosout-1.log].
log file: /home/pieter/.ros/log/7ffad4de-6459-11ea-bb82-4074e0a32f05/rosout-1*.log
```

In this forum i read it´s probably because the LD_LIBRARY_PATH changed or that some link is wrong.
When i echo it returns `/home/pieter/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` what seems right.

when run `rospack find roscpp` it return `/opt/ros/kinetic/share/roscpp` and when i run `rospack find libroscpp` i can´t find the package. /opt/ros/kinetic/lib contains libroscpp.so

`ldd /opt/kinetic/lib/rosout/rosout` returns:

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8a73435000)
libapr-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00007f8a6fe05000)
libaprutil-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaprutil-1.so.0 (0x00007f8a6fbde000)
libboost_chrono.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f8a7145f000)
libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f8a71247000)
libboost_regex.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f8a70444000)
libboost_system.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f8a7188d000)
libboost_thread.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f8a71667000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8a71eb8000)
libconsole_bridge.so.0.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libconsole_bridge.so.0.2 (0x00007f8a70037000)
libcpp_common.so => /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libcpp_common.so (0x00007f8a71a91000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f8a6eda7000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8a6efdf000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f8a6eb7e000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8a72282000)
libicudata.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55 (0x00007f8a6d0c7000)
libicui18n.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.55 (0x00007f8a6f77c000)
libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x00007f8a6f3e8000)
liblog4cxx.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblog4cxx.so.10 (0x00007f8a7074c000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8a70f3e000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8a7281a000)
librosconsole.so => /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librosconsole.so (0x00007f8a72e67000)
librosconsole_backend_interface.so => /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librosconsole_backend_interface.so (0x00007f8a70b23000)
librosconsole_log4cxx.so => /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so (0x00007f8a70d25000)
libroscpp.so => /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libroscpp.so (0x00007f8a73099000)
libroscpp_serialization.so => /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libroscpp_serialization.so (0x00007f8a72c64000)
librostime.so => /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librostime.so (0x00007f8a72a37000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f8a7023c000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8a72498000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f8a6f1e3000)
libxmlrpcpp.so => /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libxmlrpcpp.so (0x00007f8a71c99000)
```

I am a noob at ROS and can´t find a solution please help me :( Did i link wrong? Should my workspace also be linked? Or is it something else?

Thanks for reading.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346578/%C2%B4libroscpp.so:-cannot-open-shared-object-file:-no-such-file-or-directory%C2%B4-error/) by [kopop8](https://answers.ros.org/users/52035/kopop8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2020-03-12

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kopop8](https://answers.ros.org/users/52035/kopop8/) on 2020-03-12**:
Reinstalling ROS doesnt work either

**Comment by [Rextab](https://answers.ros.org/users/61528/rextab/) on 2020-11-26**:
I have the same kinda issue on 2 different computer using ROS1 and ROS2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a potential solution for you see: https://answers.ros.org/question/366380/ubuntu1804ros2-dashing-failed-to-load-entry-point-issue/

---

Originally posted by [Rextab](https://answers.ros.org/users/61528/rextab/) with karma: 71 on 2020-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on 2021-06-08**:
This fixed my problem, see https://answers.ros.org/question/366380/ubuntu1804ros2-dashing-failed-to-load-entry-point-issue/?answer=366439#post-id-366439

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2023-02-23**:
quoting the solution from the above link : "Indeed, thank you so much for this! A setcap on my Python executable was the reason for rosout terminating immediately due to not finding libroscpp.so (although properly installed, Ubuntu 20.04, ROS1 noetic). Was able to fix it with sudo setcap -r /usr/bin/python3.8"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

add this line to your bashrc file:
it should be added last,otherwise it doesn't work

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/lib
```

---

Originally posted by [mobiiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/68477/mobiiin/) with karma: 31 on 2021-07-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/346578/libroscppso-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory-error/?answer=382778#post-id-382778) that suggests adding `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the `lib` folder under ROS' install directory, then you should run `source /opt/ros/%YOUR_ROS_DISTRO%/setup.bash` (in your example, %YOUR_ROS_DISTRO%=kinetic) and see if it resolves.

`setup.bash` sets up number of things on your terminal for ROS, including setting up an environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. See http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2022-08-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1